# How can I make the changes of a transformation stick?

Tags: wpf, rotation, transform, render

So I have a `FrameworkElement` to which I apply a template that has a thumb. I calculate the angle and then I set the `RenderTransfrom` property equal to a `RotationTranform`. Once I do the rotation and want to do another rotation, the changes don't stick, that it the element returns to its initial position. How can I make the changes stick after a transformation has been applied. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Do transformations affect the actual element or are they only a rendering thing? Also do they affect the bounding box of the element? I tried a layout transformation and still the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have one tranform at a time, but if you need multiple transfomations you can use a [`TransformGroup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.transformgroup.aspx) to add whatever transforms you need.

Alternatively you can use a [`MatrixTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.matrixtransform.aspx) whose [Matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.matrixtransform.matrix.aspx) you can manipulate (those changes will not be reversible but as there is only one transformation in total it should have a higher performance).

Comment: How can I make the previous rotation affect the element, so when I apply another rotation, it picks up where the last rotation left off. Doesn't the transformations affect the actual positioning of the element?

Comment: @mihajlv: Transforms are not permanent, if you want the previous rotation to remain, leave it in the children collection of a transform group and add a new transform or get the old one and add the angle to the existing rotation.